# nodejs zip archiver issue with directory path in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, zip, node-archiver, archiverjs

I'm having an issue with using `zip.directory` in Windows.

This is the file structure I'm trying to create:

`.
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt`

`file2.txt` and `file3.txt` are coming from a directory called `dir`.

Here is the code I have on my server:

```
const zip = archiver('zip')

zip.append('some text', { name: 'file1.txt' })   
zip.directory('dir/', '.')
zip.finalize()
```

This works fine on Mac. However, using the `'.'` to put everything in the same directory seems to not work on Windows (basically only `file1.txt` makes it into the zip).

The following, however, DOES work:

```
const zip = archiver('zip')

zip.append('some text', { name: 'file1.txt' })   
zip.directory('dir/', 'somename')
zip.finalize()
```

However, this gives a folder structure like this:

`.
├── file1.txt
└── somename
    ├── file2.txt
    └── file3.txt`

which isn't really what I'm looking for. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer on the #node.js IRC channel.

Replacing this line:

```
zip.directory('dir/', '.')
```

with:

```
zip.directory('dir/', '../')
```

fixed the issue.